# How do I apply Table-per-type EF4 to create records in sub-tables inheriting from aspnet_Users?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, table-per-type

From the regular aspnet_Users table I have created two sub-tables with one to one relationship on UserId.

```
Table UserClient
-UserId int PK
-ClientNumber int

Table UserEmployee
-UserId int PK
-EmployeeNumber int
```

I have created a Table per Type model in the edmx and now wish to create the appropriate record in the appropriate sub-table when I create a new aspnet_User record through the membership stored procedures, as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(CreateUserModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    // Attempt to create the user
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

         if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
             {
             //now that the aspnet_user record is created...

             FilingBizEntities db = new FilingBizEntities();

             //Get the role chosen for the user from selectlist on the CreateUser page
             var thisrole = db.aspnet_Role.Where(rn => rn.RoleId == model.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();

             //Add the user to the role 
             Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, thisrole.RoleName);

             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
             }
             else
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
             }
         }

         ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
         return View(model);
     }
```

Whether it is of type "UserClient" or "UserEmployee" is dependent on its RoleId, which I currently differentiate when needed by query. Now I wish to extend each type's properties by having tables.

Let's say the newly created user is a Client.

How do I insert a record into the UserClient table with it's aspnet_Users' UserId and this ClientNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create a Client for an existing User is to use a **stored procedure**; not a stored procedure that is wired up to the Client entity through mappings, but a separate one that can be called explicitly from the code.

Ideally it would be a SP that takes a UserId as a parameter, inserts a new row into the UserClient table using that UserId, and then returns a complete Client object so that it can be used immidiately.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it make more sense to create a *complimentary* table, let's call it "Users" and apply TPT to that?

Your "Users" table would have a FK to the "aspnet_Users" table (guid or email). Then have your two tables deriving from *that* table.

If you want to do things specific to authentication/membership, use the built-in membership provider API.

If you want to do things specific to your domain model, use your TPH model.

In your above example ("Create Model" method), call the Membership API method: `MembershipService.CreateUser` (as you are doing), and then if it succeeds, call another method called `UserDomainService.CreateUser` which would accept the FK (guid or email) for the user just creates, and persist that new user into your TPH model.

Comment: Thank you, I have used this method now and would check it as answer except that the answer below about using the stored procedure is closer to the crux of the original question.

Comment: No problems. Just thought i'd offer an alternative.